# How to convert a short computer name (computer210) to a fully qualified domain name (computer210.test.mycompany.com)?

Tags: delphi, winapi, window, fqdn

Is there any api or function to convert a short computer name (computer210) to a fully qualified domain name (computer210.test.mycompany.com)? I m under Delphi if it's matter.

Comment: [GetComputerNameEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getcomputernameexw)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get fully qualified domain name on Windows in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446940/how-to-get-fully-qualified-domain-name-on-windows-in-delphi)

Comment: @Olivier But I don't understand GetComputerNameEx() is for my local computer so How I can convert computer210 to computer210.test.mycompany.com when computer210 is not my local computer ?

Comment: @mirtheil same answer I made for Olivier, your link point to GetComputerNameEx() and It's only for my local computer

Comment: You can use `GetComputerNameEx()` to get the domain name (use the `ComputerNameDnsDomain` type) and append it to the computer name.

Comment: what you mean under *convert* ? if task - get name, but not convert - need call `LsaQueryInformationPolicy` with `PolicyDnsDomainInformation` and `PolicyAccountDomainInformation`. you faster of all want `DnsDomainName` from `POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO`